# Why does jisho.org not give 置く as a result for “おきます”?

Tags: discussion, resources

If I do a search on jisho.org for おきます, I get matches for 起きる and 熾きる through deinflection, but not 置く, even though 置きます does. Is this because 起きる and 熾きる have pronunciations of おきる whereas 置く has a pronunciation of おく, and jisho.org fails to try "おく" after trying "おきる"?

Comment: I previously asked this on Language Learning, and it was rejected there. https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/why-does-jisho-org-not-give-%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%8F-as-a-result-for-%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99

Comment: If you type in よんで, it suggests よむ (hiragana of 読む) but not よぶ (hiragana of 呼ぶ).

Answer (score 3):

If you search for `おきます`, jisho.org gives you a little popup saying

> おきます could be an inflection of おきる, with these forms:
>   Masu-form. It is the polite form of the verb.

My guess is that the answer to your question is something along the lines of "*because the code for unconjugating search terms produces only one suggestion, and tries ichidan verbs first*". Basically, I think you're right on the mark.

That said, the only people who can really give you an answer as to why `置く` is not a result of searches for `おきます` are going to be the jisho.org authors, because this is a function of they way they've built their site. You can find their contact info on [jisho.org's "about" page](http://jisho.org/about).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it is an issue with how jisho.org searches for inflected words, as you suggested. Online Japanese dictionaries usually provide all possible variations of a search term which is an inflected word. For example, [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99) gives 置く in its suggestions for おきます.

Furthermore, if you search for かえります on [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99), it says *"Searched for かえる. No matches for かえります"*. Then it shows the correct 帰る first but also suggests 変える and 換える, which do **not** conjugate as かえります. That could be potentially confusing for beginners, I imagine. It might be worth contacting them to make them aware of the issue. If you get any further with this, please comment on this thread with any updates :)